# Solace integration approach Apache Qpid JMS client(non-Solace JMS API) or Solace JMS API

Tags: spring-jms, solace

I am trying to connect to a Solace queue as a java client(using spring jms) and found the following approaches

1. Apache Qpid JMS client(non-Solace JMS API)
2. Solace JMS API

Which of the these 2 approaches are recommended and any advantages/disadvantages over one another. Any guidance would be helpful.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2):

Approach #2 is the recommended approach as the Solace JMS API is full-featured and has been thoroughly developed and tested by Solace.

The Apache Qpid JMS client uses the AMQP protocol to communicate with Solace. While it is supported to use this protocol with Solace, there are some features that are currently not available with AMQP. Using the proprietary Solace JMS API will give you full control over features such as transactional messaging (XA distributed or local), direct messaging, and the PubSub+ broker's internal JNDI store.

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Approach #2 is definitely recommended, and one obvious advantage is support either through here, or your support contract with Solace.

Approach #1 might be just as good though, but I don't have first hand experience with it. It sounds like it could give you a slightly smoother multi-vendor transition experience if you switch from one AMQP-capable message broker to another. But the JMS abstraction is supposed to give your application vendor independence either way.

Answer (score 0):

if you go with the AMQP protocol then some features not available and you will face lot of connectivity issues. better you go with solace JMS API.